# Dishwasher not filling after replacing sink faucet

Tags: faucet, dishwasher

Yesterday I replaced my kitchen sink faucet because the old one started leaking. In the process I turned off the dishwasher line. Today when I turned that line back on and tried to run the dishwasher, the dishwasher isn't getting any water, even though the faucet is open.

I can verify that hot water is coming up the faucet (into the sink), but none is passing through to the dishwasher by feeling the pipes warm up when the kitchen faucet is on and the dishwasher is also trying to run.

My best guess is that there might be debris in the line, so that the faucet isn't opening properly. Perhaps I could turn off the main water supply and unscrew the faucet to clear the line. But, I'm a bit hesitant to do this without confirmation that there isn't another better approach.

Edit:

Here is the view under the sink with each of the lines labeled.

[image: View under the sink]

Edit 2:

Here is the view inside the shutoff valve. The metal ring inside is somewhat loose.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally it is that the shutoff valve that you closed never reopened.   Really even if it is debris you are probably forced at this point of removing the valve just to troubleshoot.   There is no use disconnecting the dishwasher as this probably isn't the issue and by disconnecting you are causing potentially more issues.   If you have pics I can give you more exacts.

**Update:**  Based on your current pictures.  I would give up on the valve.   There is a problem.   The turn valves are notoriously bad breaking like this.   It isn't that I don't think you could pop this open but why spend time working on something that is broke.

I am not sure what the line is to the dishwasher - just guessing it is 1/4".  Depending on how much play you have I suggest unless you have a lot of plumbing experience that you install something like [this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/SharkBite-Brass-1-2-in-Push-to-Connect-x-1-4-in-Push-to-Connect-Quarter-Turn-Straight-Valve/1000680165?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-rpe-_-google-_-pla-_-142-_-sospipeandfittings-_-1000680165-_-0&placeholder=null&gclid=Cj0KCQjwka_1BRCPARIsAMlUmEqs74Nt14mOqI6FMHJE2d0pKO-bLEV3Aex7Gekxf-FiizdtlFPUtK8aAh-oEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).   Soldering a wet connection is hard, soldering a wet connection in a space like that is a pro job.   If you get the longest connector (sharkbite type - varies by store) you might be able to get by just cutting off each side, cleaning, and connecting.

Also while at store get a 1/2" cap in case you have an issue and a release cup (sharkbite's cap is like $2 and release is like $1).   Always good to have a cap on hand so that you can turn your water back on when there is still an issue.

Comment: I would first try to open and close that quite a few times and and put a little force when you "open" all the way and "close" all the way.   Really if it is broke you are trying to let it stay broke in the open position.   I highly doubt lines that big are blocked.

Comment: Thanks - tried that, but I'm still not seeing any flow into the dishwasher.

Comment: Hard to tell from the pic but the shutoff looks like one of the old style with a washer and a threaded cap beneath the handle. If it is, turn off your main and unscrew the brass cap. You might be able to repair it. The washer may have disintegrated and blocked the flow.

Comment: @HoneyDo It is - I've turned off the main water and am trying to unscrew it, but it's quite stuck for the time being - I will keep at it and see what I can do.

Comment: I've updated with another picture inside the valve - I haven't dealt with this type of valve internally before, so I don't know how it's supposed to look, but the metal ring inside is loose.

Comment: post a pic of the part(s) of the valve that you unscrewed and removed. It sounds like the valve stem is stripped and will no longer move the wedge/gate/bib to open the valve. You may as well start planning to replace the valve. If you don't know how to solder pipe there is no better time than now to learn.

Comment: Thanks; I'll see what I can find to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

After significantly more investigation, it ends up that significant debris from the shutoff valve had entered the pipe and completely blocked a filter inside the dishwasher, so no water was moving to the dishwasher. The one hint (not in the pictures I posted) was that the valve portion of the shutoff had significant particle buildup on it.

Pulling out the dishwasher and completely cleaning out the filter was sufficient to get things working again. (Note that this wasn't clearly a filter - it was just a pipe with small holes inside a larger unit on the side of the dishwasher.)